# Mercurial: alias with arguments

Tags: mercurial, alias

I want to create an alias so that when I run:

```
hg pushbranch <<SOME_BRANCH>>
```

it aliases to:

```
hg push -b <<SOME_BRANCH>>
```

Where `SOME_BRANCH` is the name of a branch I wish to push.  I can create an alias in my `.hgrc`, but don't know how I could supply an argument to the alias.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [hgrc help](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias)

> Positional arguments in the form of $1, $2, etc in the alias
>   definition are expanded by Mercurial before execution.

Thus, your alias definition, which will allow to push *any* branch, will be

`pushbranch = push -b $1`

and `hg pushbranch mybranch` is expanded to `hg push -b mybranch`

Comment: In the example in the original version of this answer, %1 should be $1, but stackoverflow currently won't take an edit from me less than 6 characters.  Please fix.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add the arguments in your alias. Some examples from my configuration:

```
[alias]
log0 = log -l 10
tipr = tip --template "{node|short}"
```

If you provide additional arguments, they'll simply be appended. For example, the following will be functionally equivalent to `log -l 10 -k Refactoring`.

```
$ hg log0 -k Refactoring
```