# Create a Mercurial alias that runs two commands and takes one paramater

Tags: mercurial, alias, dvcs

I'm trying to create an alias and allows me to commit my changes and push all changesets for the current branch.
I'm running this from a Windows command prompt.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098085/how-is-it-possible-to-create-an-hg-command-alias-that-runs-multiple-commands) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009414/mercurial-alias-with-arguments) and so far have this:

```
ci-push = !hg ci -m $1 && hg push -b .
```

When I try this i get the error:

> abort: Commit: The system cannot find the file specified

If I try:

```
ci-push = !hg ci -m %1 && hg push -b .
```

then it appears to work (prompts for auth and pushes the commit), but my commit message is:

> %1

Is this even possible from a Windows cmd prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, `%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`:

```
[alias]
ll = log -l$1
```

Testing:

```
>hg ll
abort: too few arguments for command alias

> hg ll 5
changeset:...
```

Shell alias (`%USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini`):

```
[alias]
ld = !hg log -r $1 && hg diff -r $1
```

Testing:

```
>hg ld 154
changeset:   154:5bb3aba44eab
....

diff -r 5bb3aba44eab ....
```

P.S.
When using `$N` with spaces you should use quotes (`!hg ci -m "$1" ...` in aliases).